# How to find contacts that haven't confirmed their registration?

Tags: search, groups

Coming through various channels (webform, newsletter subscription, api calls..) I have contacts that have never confirmed their subscription to a group.

If I go to the group tab, I can see that they belong to the group with the status "pending", and can manually confirm them

However, I didn't find on advanced search or custom a way to list all the pending ones (ideally, from longer than a few days ago), so I can send them a nudge "hey, you haven't confirmed your registration yet, please click here"

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to >Contacts >Manage Groups and click on the link "Contacts" next to the the group in question. You will then see all contacts in the group and also be able to filter for those that are added, removed or pending.

Comment: duh, how could I miss that one! many thanks

Comment: But there seems to be no way to nudge them to confirm. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19369/how-can-i-chase-up-mailing-list-subscribers-who-dont-confirm-their-opt-in