# Is there a way to send an opt-in reminder (with a subscribe link to click) to people whose group status is pending?

Tags: civimail, profile, groups, tokens, scheduled-reminders

I have the same problem that was described here in 2017: [How can I chase up mailing list subscribers who don't confirm their opt-in?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19369/how-can-i-chase-up-mailing-list-subscribers-who-dont-confirm-their-opt-in)

I am wondering if anyone has found a solution. To summarize the issue, when people sign up for our newsletter, we're using a double opt-in configuration to reduce spam, but I can't find a way to send a reminder to potentially legitimate sign ups who haven't opted in yet and their group status is still pending.

I'm wondering if there is now a way to send a scheduled reminder which includes the subscribe token, or a way to get the token to work in civimail, which I could then manually send out on a regular basis.

Thanks all

Comment: First idea: 1.) define smart group(s) with your pending subscribers, 2.) create a form processor which sends email by template to smart group and 3.) (web) cron job to schedule posts to form processor.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would the token work if I did it this way? I am currently able to contact the pending subscribers manually but the subscribe token doesn't work, so all I can do is ask them to look for the original email we sent them.

Comment: Formprocessor allows utilizing email templates with tokens. I would just try.